# Ionic: Center text vertically in card

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to center the text in my card vertically and horizontally. But it is just centered horizontal. I do not know what I can do different.

**index.html**

```
<body id="bb" ng-app="starter" ng-controller="AppCtrl" style="background-color: lightblue;height:1000px;">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="item item-divider">
            <h2><b>Joke {{jokeNo}}</b></h2>
        </div>
        <div class="item item-text-wrap">
            <h1>{{joke}}</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="control">
        <button id="nextJokeButton" class="button button-outline button-positive" ng-click="loadJoke()">
            Another one
        </button>

        <button id="rateButton" class="button button-outline button-positive" ng-click="rate()">
            Rate us
        </button>

    </div>
</body>
```

**style.css**

```
#nextJokeButton{
  margin-top:50px;
}

.control{
    text-align:center;
}

.card{
     height: 30%;
     margin-top:5%;
     text-align:center;
     vertical-align: middle;
     margin-top: 50px; 
}

h1 {
    font-size: 23px;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `display:table-cell;` in css.

Comment: Still not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the line height for the .item class and the vertical-align in the h1 and h2 sould work:

```
.item{ line-height: Xpx;}
.item .h1{ vertical-align:middle; }
.item .h2{ vertical-align:middle; }
```

UPDATE

You could use

```
position:relative;top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%);
```

In the h2.

Comment: Did you have any other styles in the page? I'm trying right now in my browser and it works (with i.e a line-height of 100 in the item). Check: https://jsfiddle.net/pjnt6k9b/

Comment: The content of the item is only the h2? I don't like this but you can try to set to h2 the style: `position:relative;top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` and it should work or you can take a look at: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/ if you i.e don't know the height of the block.

Comment: Hi @Kewitschka if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.